# Strange behavior when adding the Send trait to a boxed trait object

Tags: multithreading, rust, compiler-errors, thread-safety, traits

Here's an error struct:

```rust
#[derive(Debug)]
pub struct Error {
    msg: &'static str,
  //source: Option<Box<dyn std::error::Error>>,        // old
    source: Option<Box<dyn std::error::Error + Send>>, // new
}

impl Error {
    fn new_caused<E>(msg: &'static str, err: E) -> Self
    where
        E: 'static + std::error::Error + Send,
    {
        Self {
            msg: msg,
            source: Some(Box::from(err)),
        }
    }
}

impl std::fmt::Display for Error {
    fn fmt(&self, fmt: &mut std::fmt::Formatter) -> std::fmt::Result {
        write!(fmt, "{}", self.msg) // HACK
    }
}

impl std::error::Error for Error {
    fn source(&self) -> Option<&(dyn std::error::Error + 'static)> {
        self.source.as_ref().map(|err| err.as_ref())
    }
}

fn main() {
    let err = "this will fail".parse::<i32>().unwrap_err();
    let err = Error::new_caused("some msg", err);
}
```

I decided to make it `Send`able so I changed `source: Option<Box<dyn std::error::Error>>` to `source: Option<Box<dyn std::error::Error + Send>>` and strange things happened.

## Magic #1

`new_caused` refused to compile any more:

```
error[E0277]: the trait bound `std::boxed::Box<dyn std::error::Error + std::marker::Send>: std::convert::From<E>` is not satisfied
  --> src/main.rs:14:26
   |
14 |             source: Some(Box::from(err)),
   |                          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ the trait `std::convert::From<E>` is not implemented for `std::boxed::Box<dyn std::error::Error + std::marker::Send>`
   |
   = note: required by `std::convert::From::from`
```

Changing `Box::from` to `Box::new` helped, even though their signatures seem identical and `Box::from`'s implementation just calls `Box::new`.

## Magic #2

`source` also became incorrect:

```
error[E0308]: mismatched types
  --> src/main.rs:27:9
   |
27 |         self.source.as_ref().map(|err| err.as_ref())
   |         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ expected trait `std::error::Error`, found trait `std::error::Error + std::marker::Send`
   |
   = note: expected enum `std::option::Option<&(dyn std::error::Error + 'static)>`
              found enum `std::option::Option<&dyn std::error::Error + std::marker::Send>`
```

Why isn't the unused `Send` trait ignored like other ones?

Replacing that combinator logic with its manual version worked fine:

```
fn source(&self) -> Option<&(dyn std::error::Error + 'static)> {
    match &self.source {
        Some(source) => Some(source.as_ref()),
        None => None
    }
}
```

## Summary

What are the explanations for this "magic" and what are better methods of dealing with it?

Comment: @Shepmaster that's it, I believe: https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=9f04b85103370ce421c880aa051439f0.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For magic #1, it is because the standard library has these implementations:

```
impl<'a, E: Error + 'a> From<E> for Box<dyn Error + 'a>
impl<'a, E: Error + Send + Sync + 'a> From<E> for Box<dyn Error + Send + Sync + 'a>
```

There is no implementation for `E: Error + Send` without the `Sync`.

Easy solution #1: add `Sync` whereever there is a `Send` or use `Box::new`.

Magic #2 is more complicated: you have an `std::option::Option<&dyn std::error::Error + Sync>` where you need an `Option<&dyn std::error::Error>`. You know that a `&(dyn std::error::Error + Send)` is convertible to a `&dyn std::error::Error` so you expect that the `Option<_>` will be too, but those conversions are not transitive<sup>1</sup>, so it fails.

The difference between the `map` and the `match` is in the order of type deduction:

In the `map` case, the type of the closure is deduced as taking a `Box<dyn std::error::Error + Sync>`. Since it returns `err.as_ref()`, of type `&dyn std::error::Error + Sync`, that is the type that the closure returns. Then `Option::map` returns an `Option<_>` with the same type of the closure return type so you get a final `Option<&dyn std::error::Error + Sync>` and an error.

In the `match` code, when you write `Some(source) => Some(source.as_ref())`, `source` is deduced as type `Box<dyn std::error::Error + Sync>`, but the right side is deduced from the returned type `Option<&dyn std::error::Error>`, so the argument to `Some` is cast to that type: `source.as_ref()` is converted to the right type and it compiles.

I think the easiest way to write this example is to add a cast `as _` inside the map, to instruct the compiler to deduce the type of the closure from the usage instead of from the inner code:

```
self.source.as_ref().map(|err| err.as_ref() as _)
```

If the code is more complex, `as _` may not be feasible. Then a `match` is perfectly adequate.

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=f5d57f79224be6eb2c602fc73dd9431a) with the fixed code.

---

1: I think I read about making these conversions automatic (*covariant* on auto traits?) but I cannot find it anywhere...

Comment: I always have to spend a long time thinking through them and usually get it wrong, so I'm no help there!